# Question about light that goes through long thin tunnel

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

Assume I have a thick wall made of material that is almost a black body. I have a very long hole in that wall (tunnel). The hole is very thin with diameter near $0.005 \ mm$, but diameter is still more than wave length of visible light. The inner surface of that hole is almost ideal, I mean there is no roughness. Then I start flashing the light throught that hole.

My question is :

Will the beam of light have cylidrical form after the wall or it will be scattered? If it will be scattered then how can I get nonscattered beam? I mean cone of light with little angle, that is not laser.

Comment: https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Fiber_Optics_Understanding_the_Basics/a25151

Comment: @anna Thanks, but the question is about what will be after the light passes through tunnel, not what happens in.

Comment: You'll probably get a lot of diffraction at the exit of the tunnel. With the diameter of your tunnel compared to the wavelength of visible light you're probably way beyond any useful aperture and diffraction limited. https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/limitations-on-resolution-and-contrast-the-airy-disk/

Comment: fig2, you can download the article https://rmf.smf.mx/ojs/index.php/rmf-e/article/view/5234

Comment: @anna Thanks. Is it possible to create a lense that I put at the end of the hole, so there will be no diffraction.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов  I would not think it can be done, but optics is not my specialty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a cone of light the only way is to have a collimated beam, of a smaller wavelength, passing through the hole. In all other circumstances, you'll get a diffracting beam. Regarding the lens, you can not avoid diffraction with a lens after the tunnel exit, but you can try to collimate it...but it will probably be quite difficult